# Aligning text left

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working with code here: https://codepen.io/codepen818/pen/YzZxprN

[image]

I would like to have the first `li` child to `text-align: left`:

[image]

I've tried to add the following style, but it does not change the text position.

```
.progress-bar li:first-child span {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: ?? Just change your CSS to `.progress-bar li:first-child`. You don't need/want 'span' there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for the `first child` as a parent . . . THEN `span` ..  You should remove the `span` as is **is** the first child:

```
.progress-bar li:first-child {
      text-align:left;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the `<li>` container is center aligned change it to left.

```
.progress-bar li {
  flex: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 14px 0;
  font-size: var(--font-size-default);
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--color-green);
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  min-width: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-gray-disabled);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the rest of the `<li>` elements .. They are supposed to be centered ..  Hence the fact they are trying to make sure that the first element is not centered with child - parent relationships.